# Ping on Linux with Bind produces a round robin effect?

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, bind

I am setting up DNS (Bind 9.8.1) on a Ubuntu 12.04. I some CNAMEs for the server. When I ping the server it bounces though all the names. Is this default behavior? How can I get this just to respond just on the name that you ping?

This is from the main config file.

```
$TTL    3D
@   IN  SOA ns.zzz.net. info@zzz.net. (
                    2013041314  ; serial
                    8H      ; refresh
                    2H      ; retry    
                    4W      ; expire
                    1D )        ; minimum
    IN  TXT "zzz Inc."
    IN  NS  ns ;ns address (unqualified)
    IN  NS  ns.zzz.net. ;ns address (qualified)
www IN  CNAME   ns
ftp IN  CNAME   ns
```

This is from the Reverse Lookup file.

```
$TTL    3D
@   IN  SOA ns.zzz.net. info@zzz.net. (
                    2013041315  ; serial
                    8H      ; refresh
                    2H      ; retry    
                    4W      ; expire
                    1D )        ; minimum
    IN  NS  ns.zzz.net.
53  IN  PTR www.zzz.net.
53  IN  PTR ftp.zzz.net.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by "bounces trough all the names" means that you get different hostnames on every ping: You entered more than one PTR for the IP (.53). It is random which one is returned.

Btw., the "unqualified NS" in your SOA will be "qualified" to ns.zzz.net. by BIND (always assuming that the zonefile you showed is for zzz.net). If you have no "." on the end the current zone will be appended to any entry. So you effectively only have one NS in your zone (ns.zzz.net).